# How to infer the parameter $p = f(n)$ of different Bernoulli distributions $X_{n}$?

Tags: probability, inference, bernoulli-distribution

I have a dataset corresponding to the results of independant Bernoulli trials. Each trial is associated to a number $n \in ]1;+\infty[$ and follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p=f(n)=b + a/n$. The problem is almost each trial has a different $n$ so follows a different Bernoulli distribution.

Here is a part of my dataset:

```
 n      result of the trial
 1.47   1
 3.21   0
10.22   0
 1.17   1
 1.17   0
 2.12   1
 1.82   0
...
```

How can I find the most likely $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Just to be clear, $n$ has nothing to do with sample size? And it's not a natural number either. Is this a regression problem where $n$ (better called "$x$") is an independent variable that relates to the probability of outcome according to the linear model you show above?

Comment: @AdamO Yes. In others words, $n$ is a "hint" about the true parameter $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a problem easily solved by additive risk models. Create the regressor 1/n and estimate the additive risk model relating 1/n to the outcome $y$, you will obtain maximum likelihood estimates of $a$ and $b$. This is one of a general class of "binomial models" which are among a general class of "generalized linear models".

The most famous example in this class is logistic regression which attributes to the outcome outcome a binomial variance, i.e. that the variance is equal to the mean times one minus the mean, and that the mean response is related to the predictors through a "logit link". $$\log \left( \text{Pr}(Y|X) / (1-\text{Pr}(Y|X)) \right) = X^T\beta$$.

However one can maintain the binomial variance attribute and vary the link. In particular, additive risk uses the identity function as the "link":

$$\text{Pr}(Y|X) = X^T\beta$$

which in 1-dimension is exactly the linear model you express above.

Estimation is done through maximum likelihood and Fisher Scoring in most default software. In R, for instance, the "call" is `glm(y ~ x, family=binomial(link="identity")`. In fact, there are some antiquated warnings in the `?glm` help file about not fitting such a model. But these dismiss the importance of additive risk models and of using alternative fitting strategies (there is ample discussion on *that* topic through this SE).

Comment: I don't understand the references to logit and identity links when the question is manifestly a Binomial GLM with *reciprocal* link.  It might help to connect your "$X$" more explicitly with the $n$ in the question.

Comment: @whuber good point, such an obvious one I neglected to mention it, so now edited. It should be noted it is not a reciprocal link, since the term $a$ in OP's linear model should be the probability of response when $X=0$, reciprocal link would have $1/a$ as that value (a being the intercept term).

Comment: running `glm(resultofthetrial ~ 1/n, family=binomial(link="identity"))` gives me only an estimate for $b$. How do I recover $a$?

Comment: Answering my own question: you need to save `1/n` explicitly in a new variable for the function call to work. E.g. `onebyn <- 1/n; glm(resultofthetrial ~ onebyn, family=binomial(link="identity"))` or even `lm(resultofthetrial ~ onebyn)`. Nice!

Comment: @Edgar `lm` doesn't get correct error estimates. You'll need to calculate robust error estimates to get the right 95% CIs and P values if those are of any use.

Comment: Right--thanks for correcting my misinformation about a "reciprocal link."  I'm glad you understood what I meant!

Comment: @Edgar R's "formula" syntax is very tricky. And it's worth reading about. If you want 1/n as a regressor, use the insular function I. That is: `glm(y ~ I(1/n))`. This prevents the formula from parsing out algebra syntax as inputs to the model matrix. For instance, see the difference in `terms(~a*b)` and `terms(~I(a*b))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** Do you have any bounds or relation between $a$ and $b$?

If you don't, suppose $n = 10$, you have many answers for $a$ and $b$ that satisfies $p = 0.5$:

- $b = 0$ and $a = 5$
- $b = 1$ and $a = -5$
- $b = 10$ and $a = -95$

If you do have bounds or relationship between your parameters, since you have clear Bernoulli experiment with a custom parameter, I would recommend you to write your likelihood as a function of $a$ and $b$ and use `optim` function in R.

There is an incomplete sample code that should help you to implement in your experiment, but please notice the parts where you should insert your values based on the bounds and relationship I mentioned before.

````
loglik = function(pars, n, result){
a = pars[1]
b = pars[2]
my_p = b + a/n

## Your log likelihood
lk = sum(result*log(my_p) + (1-result)*log(1 - my_p))

## Return negative to maximize it
return(-lk)
}

## init_par = <insert your initial value>
my_n = c(1.47, 3.21, 10.22, 1.17, 1.17, 2.12, 1.82)
my_result = c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0)

optim(par = init_par, 
      fun = loglik,  
      method = "L-BFGS-B",
      n = my_n, 
      result = my_result,
##    lower = c(<low_a>, <low_b>),
##    upper = c(<up_a>, <up_b>)
     )

```
````

Comment: Why do you use log-likelihood rather than likelihood?

Comment: @Pierre much better behaved in Quasi-Newton optimization routines.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. If a=-95 then the fitted probabilities are negative. Try drawing the 2-D likelihood function with `contour` to see why this is wrong.

Comment: @Pierre Maximizing the log-likelihood is equivalent to maximize the likelihood, since log is a monotone transformation. Computationally, I can't say for sure but it may be preferable to deal with sums rather than products.

Answer (score 1):

I did a very rough approximation to $a$ and $b$ via a system of equations. In your data, you sort all of the $n$ values and bin them (in the code below I made bins of same length, it would be probably better to make bins with roughly equal number of $n$'s inside). You count how many $1$'s and $0$'s are in your bins ($\#_1$ and $\#_{1\&0}$), and how many $n$'s fall into this range ($\#_n$). Then you have: $\#_1/\#_{1\&0} = \sum_{n's}(b + a\cdot\frac{1}{n})/\#_n$ for every bin, where only $a$ and $b$ are unknown.

This gives a system of equations. See my example solution in R below:

```
a <- 0.5
b <- 0.2

B <- 1000000

set.seed(2407)
n <- runif(B, 1, 1000)
bn <- rbinom(B, 1, b+a/n) # result of the trials

bins <- 10
grid <- seq(min(n), max(n), length.out = bins+1)
lhs <- rep(0, bins)
for_a <- rep(0, bins)
for (i in 1:bins) {
  lhs[i] <- sum(bn[n>=grid[i] & n<grid[i+1]])/length(bn[n>=grid[i] & n<grid[i+1]])
  for_a[i] <- sum(1/n[n>=grid[i] & n<grid[i+1]])/length(n[n>=grid[i] & n<grid[i+1]])
}

indices <- !is.na(for_a) & !is.na(lhs)
for_a <- for_a[indices]
lhs <- lhs[indices]
for_b <- rep(1, length(for_a))

lm(lhs ~ -1+for_a+for_b)
```

The results look okay, but some trials showed that especially in $a$ is a lot of variation:

```
Call:
lm(formula = lhs ~ -1 + for_a + for_b)

Coefficients:
 for_a   for_b  
0.5227  0.1994
```